# How fix 'java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 60' when starting a spring application on localhost:8443

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#12, websecurity

first some context:
We are developing a web application using Java 8 and springframework.
There are currently two environments in use (Test, Stage).
This works fine.

Now we wanted to add a new environment (Development).

'Development' is configured exactly like 'Test'.
The only difference is the slightly altered url.

Still we cannot start the runnable jar.

It says:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:198)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at com.sixt.testautomation.tdm.core.CoreApplication.main(CoreApplication.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 60
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:115)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:86)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1151)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: toDerInputStream rejects tag type 60
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.toDerInputStream(DerValue.java:881)
    at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1939)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:159)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:113)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

The keystore is in place and identical to the Test-keystore. Codebase  and the run-scripts are identical.

I tried to look up the "tag type 60" but I cannot find any documentation nevermind someone with a related problem.